# formatting a value in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time, countdown

i have a working timer which returns a value every second

```
<?php
$timer = "10:00";
?>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $timer; ?>" id="timer"/>

<script>
$('.ok').click(function() {
  setInterval(function(){

  var timer=$('#timer').val();
  var time = timer.split(":");
  var timer = (parseInt(time[0])*60) + parseInt(time[1]);
  var remaining= (timer)-1;
  var minutes = parseInt( remaining / 60 ) % 60;
  var seconds = remaining % 60;
  $('#timer').val(minutes+":"+seconds);
}, 1000);
 });
</script>
```

i want the output to display mm:ss. like if the output is 9 minutes and 1 second, i want it to look like 09:01 not 9:1

Comment: how about prepending zero if digit one?

Comment: @C-link possible, but how do i do that?

Comment: @oGeez possible but mine is timer and that is date

Comment: It makes no difference. The concept is the same. Add a leading zero if the number is less than two digits long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this snippet.

```
var min = (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes);
var sec = (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
if(remaining >= 0){
    $('#timer').val( min +":"+sec);
}
```

Or if you need more options try **[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)**

Comment: nah, i don't need more options. your answer is what i am looking for.